# accessing base class variable from main() after initializing through derived class constructor

Tags: c++

Consider the following code in which Base class constructor is initialized through Derived class constructor.  When I am trying to access the Base class value `x` from `main`, it returns 0 instead of 5.  What is wrong with my understanding?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    int x;

    Base() {}
    Base(int a)
    {
        x = a;
    }
};

class Der:public Base
{
public:
    Der(int y) : Base(y)
    {
        x = y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *ob1 = new Base();
    Der *ob = new Der(5);
    cout << ob1->x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ob1` and `ob` are unrelated instances.

Comment: You might mean `Base *ob1 = new Der(5); cout << ob1->x;`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new Base()`, you get an object from the default constructor.  That happens to not initialise `x` at all, and so your code has undefined behaviour.  You happen to see `0` this time, but that is not guaranteed.

When you call `new Der(5)`, you get a *different* object, which uses the `int` constructor.  In your case, setting `x = y` inside `Der(int)` is unnecessary, because you already called `Base(y)`.  The following line should output `5`:

```
cout << ob->x;
```

Also note there is no reason to use dynamic allocation in this example.  It's perfectly okay to use the stack:

```
int main()
{
    Base base;
    Der derived(5);
    cout << "Base (undefined behaviour): " << base.x << endl;
    cout << "Derived (defined): " << derived.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. So how can i access the base class member from main() without using derived class object?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused.  You _are_ accessing the base class member in both cases.  The difference is that your `ob1` instance does not _initialise_ that member with a value.  There is an appropriate constructor that does (`Base::Base(int)`).  It's just that you aren't calling it.